# Unable to run exe files on Wine?

Tags: 12.04, wine

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and Wine 1.6.1 and I'm trying to get an exe program to run and it isn't working. I'm completely new to Wine, I just installed it for the first time like 2 hours ago, and I've been spending the last 2 hours trying to figure this out. Whenever I right click my exe file and press "Open with Wine Windows Program Loader" nothing happens. And This is what I get when I run with the terminal:

`noah@noah-HP-ENVY-m6-Notebook-PC:~$ wine Desktop/Pivot/pivot_v4-1.exe
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub`

So if anybody could tell me what this all means, and maybe a possible fix, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the Pivot Animator you are trying to run?

It doesn't look good. It currently has a 'Garbage' rating at [WineHQ AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32340) even with wine 1.7.

Maybe an older version of it might run.

Comment: Yes I was and trying an older version is exactly what I did and it ran exactly as I wanted it to.  Thank you sir.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out. :)